# Multiple Call backs with one response -Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am getting a request from client that request needs to select the data from two tables , from one table i need to select 1000 records in table two i need to select only two records, handling it with a call back . I want the response that needs to send to my client after the two callback function executes , How to achieve this in node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following options:

1. Follow Node style callback pattern. Also read, [Callback-hell](http://callbackhell.com/)
2. Follow [promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Callback pattern

```
var f  = function(somedata, cb){
    // pick user from db
    pickUserFromTable1(somedata, function(err, users){
        // callled on completion of pickUserFromDB
        if(err){
            //handle error.
            cb(err, null);
            return;
        }

        pickUserFromTable2(users, function(err, finallySelectedUsers){
            // called on completion of pickUserFromTable2
            if(err){
                // handle error.
                cb(err, null);
                // returning is important. or use else part of if to separate the case
                return;
            }

            // call initiator's callback function on completion of both pickUserFromTable1 and pickUserFromTable2
            cb(null, finallySelectedUsers);
        });
    })
}
```

Note: This approach is good for short project but leads to some maintenance issue (callback hell) if dependency chain is lengthy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my doubt is Node js is non blocking one , so the second query is depending one query one to get exectuted , it looks like blocking know? Correct me if i am wrong , i just need to asyc queries with single call back

Comment: I think i misunderstood your problem, in case where you want to run two queries run in parallel and you want to produce the output after completion of both. Then, async library parallel method will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to callback hell! You just need to build pyramide form callbacks!

Example:

```
function getDataFromDB (query, successCb, errorCb) {
    executeFirstQuery(query, function(firstQueryData) {
        console.log('First query ok! Now execute second.');

        executeSecondQuery(query, function(secondQueryData) {
            console.log('Second query ok! Now execute successCb().');

            successCb([firstQueryData, secondQueryData]);
        }, function(error) {
            errorCb("Error in second query");
        })
    }, function(error) {
        errorCb("Error in first query");
    });
}

function executeFirstQuery (query, successCb, errorCb) {
    console.log("Execute first query!");
    successCb("Some data from first query");
    // errorCb("Some Error from first query");
}

function executeSecondQuery (query, successCb, errorCb) {
    console.log("Execute second query!");
    successCb("Some from second query");
    // errorCb("Some Error from second query");
}

getDataFromDB("Some sql", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Or use a Promises: http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/